# How to target a child of a sibling div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to study JQuery and I am quite shucked on figuring our how to target a child with a specific class name of a sibling div.

Here is the fiddle that I have written: http://jsfiddle.net/7c9F4/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-image">
            <img width="100" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt="Google" />
        </div>
        <div class="item-name">
            Item 1
        </div>
        <div class="item-body">
            <div class="body-inner hidden">
                Body 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-image">
            <img width="100" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt="Google" />
        </div>
        <div class="item-name">
            Item 2
        </div>
        <div class="item-body">
            <div class="body-inner hidden">
                Body 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.item .item-image').bind({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).siblings('.item-body').children('body-inner').show();
        console.log('Entered');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).siblings('.item-body').children('body-inner').hide();
        console.log('Left');
    }
});
```

I have tried to use the JQuery methods .next() and siblings() then try to get the child using the .children() method and it doesn't seem to work. :/

Answer (score 3):

`body-inner` needs to have a `.` to indicate a class selector:

```
$(this).siblings('.item-body').children('.body-inner').hide();
```

Additionally, as of jQuery 1.7 the [.on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method is preferred to [.bind](https://api.jquery.com/bind/):

```
$('.item .item-image').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).siblings('.item-body').children('.body-inner').show();
        console.log('Entered');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).siblings('.item-body').children('.body-inner').hide();
        console.log('Left');
    }
});
```

<kbd>[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rKxa7/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine. You're just missing `.` to target class `body-inner`

```
$(this).siblings('.item-body').children('.body-inner').hide();
// ------------------------------------- ^ here
```

Also, you should use `.on()` instead of `.bind()`, final code look like:

```
$('.item .item-image').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).siblings('.item-body').children('.body-inner').show();
        console.log('Entered');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).siblings('.item-body').children('.body-inner').hide();
        console.log('Left');
    }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7c9F4/4/)**

---

I just notice that the above demo is not working properly for your second image because you've added class `hidden` for the second `.item-body`, you should remove it to make it works properly.

If you cannot modify your HTML code, then you can use **[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** and **[.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)** to remove class `hidden` from your second `.item-body`:

```
$('.item-body:eq(1)').removeClass('hidden');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7c9F4/8/)**

Comment: There is no `onhover` event

Comment: I kind of let it slide when you updated your answer after mine because it was an obvious answer. But clearly you just took A.Wolff's answer and added it to yours.

Comment: @RGraham still with a mistake ;)

Comment: @Felix As well you should, but if an answer is already there, then the OP is free to decide which answer is appropriate for them.

Comment: The answer is not only for the OP but for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use `hover` and `toggle()`:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7c9F4/5/)

```
$('.item .item-image').hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.item-body').children('.body-inner').toggle();       
});
```

PS: you should remove class `hidden` on second `.item-body` as in jsFiddle

Or using only CSS:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7c9F4/7/)

```
.item-image:hover ~ .item-body > .body-inner {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the mouse events on the outer div .item and use the .find() function in jQuery and navigate to the target element. Here is the js with .find()

```
$('.item').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
    $(this).find('.item-body .body-inner').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
    $(this).find('.item-body .body-inner').hide();
    }
});
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/giri_jeedigunta/u45Ka/